# How to create a stop button in ApplescriptObjC/xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, applescript

I have a script that loops a lot. Sometimes I will need to stop it manually. It works fine in the applescript editor because I can just hit stop, but if this is going to be a standalone app made in xcode then how would I create a stop button? I have heard something about threading, but I dont understand it yet.

lets say that my code is:

```
on buttonClicked_(sender)
   repeat        
     say "help"
   end repeat
end buttonClicked_
```

Button clicked would be a ui button that says "run"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ApplescriptObjC, but here's how to do it in objective-c. I'm sure you can figure out how to convert it.

The idea with threading is that your program runs on a main thread. When you enter the repeat loop that will take up all of your applications resources and thus block the main thread so you can't do anything else until you exit the repeat loop. Therefore run your repeat loop on a background thread, thus the main thread is free to handle other tasks, such as pressing a button.

For example, suppose you have a button on your interface and a BOOL variable setup in your code. On every button press the BOOL becomes YES/NO. Here's a button method. Notice we use "detachNewThreadSelector" to run your repeat loop on a background thread.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender {
   if (theBool == YES) {
      theBool = NO;
      [sender setTitle:@"Start"];
   } else {
      theBool = YES;
      [sender setTitle:@"Stop"];
   }
   [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(theMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

And here's what your "background thread" method could look like. Since I don't know if you're using ARC or not, it contains an autorelease pool which handles releasing memory. The main thread has one automatically but since this is on a background thread we must create our own.

```
-(void)theMethod {
   if (theBool == YES) {
      NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
      repeat
         if (theBool == NO) {
            exit repeat
         }
         say "help"
      end repeat
      [pool drain];
   }
}
```

Good luck.